# Loop with 2 Conditions. (For Loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a question below.
I have an array for example:

```
ex_ar=[1,2,3]
```

and I have an step size, for example:

```
step=5
```

I want to create a loop so that it should print each element during the step size. In this example here it should look like this:

```
1
2
3
1
2
```

```
ex_ar=[1,2,3]
step=6
for i in range(step):
    print(sayi[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use modulo list size

```
ex_ar=[1,2,3]
step=5
for i in range(step):
    print(ex_ar[i % len(ex_ar)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add two conditions on the for loop.

Alternative solution:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
for i in range(5):
    print(arr[i%len(arr)])
```